# BPF test crashes if duration >~10s

Tags: testing, unit-test

I am doing a heavy set of tests, and one of these have to create several thousands of accounts and change one specific account 1k times.

Sometimes the test runs, other times it blows up after the 950~ transaction mark.

Thought of adding some sleeps in between calls and it got worse the longer the sleeps, until I realised it crashes always after the ~11s duration mark.

The `BanksClient::process_transaction` ends up returning `RpcError(DeadlineExceeded)` after a long time (1~2min).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it: forcing the test context to advance some slots seems to fix this, test is ongoing for 5minutes without error from the `BanksClient`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you meant by _"forcing the test context to advance some slots"_?